Moving an widget in a Canvas
I want to move a widget inside of a canvas with a click of a button. Unfortunatly I always get the same Error:"_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression"
I've isolated the false Code:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()


def button():
    w.coords(checkbutton, 0, 0, 75, 25)


test = tk.BooleanVar()
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(w, text="example", variable=test, width=20, anchor="w")
w.create_window((100, 100), window=checkbutton)
button = tk.Button(w, text="Click", command=button)
button.place(x=50, y=50)
root.mainloop()

I've also triede the .configure method without any succsess.
Please help me if you have any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

The first argument of coords() is the item ID returned by .create_window(...).  Also the coordinates required for a widget item is just a position.
def button():
    w.coords(item_id, 175, 125)

...

item_id = w.create_window((100, 100), window=checkbutton)


One immediate snag I can see is that you have both a function and a variable named button. As written, the variable for your Button widget is overriding the function. I've renamed the function to move below.
The other problem is that you're passing checkbutton into w.coords(checkbutton, 0, 0, 75, 25) - checkbutton isn't a canvas item, it's a tk.Checkbutton.
Instead, you'll want to store the canvas object in a variable and pass that into the call to coords, e.g. canvas_window = w.create_window((100, 100), window=checkbutton).
Lastly, coords is only expecting two coordinates for x and y in this case, so you should call it like so: w.coords(canvas_window, 75, 25)
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()


def move():  # rename this function to avoid a conflict
    # this method only expects 2 coords not 4, but see @acw1668's comment!
    w.coords(canvas_window, 75, 25) 

test = tk.BooleanVar()
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(w, text="example", variable=test, width=20, anchor="w")
# store the canvas object ID in a variable, and pass *that* to coords()
canvas_window = w.create_window((100, 100), window=checkbutton)

button = tk.Button(w, text="Click", command=move)
button.place(x=50, y=50)

root.mainloop()


Note that coords() expects 4 values for arc, oval and rectangle item.

@acw1668 That's a good point! Thanks for the reminder
